# twitter ios5 integration autorize with custom login and password

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter

I want my ios5 application to post tweets.
I'm using this standard code from ReyWenderlich's tutorials:

```
-(void)postOnTwitter:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"postOnTwitter: called");
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting from iOS 5 By Tutorials! :)"];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection    and you have at least one Twitter account setup" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    };
}
```

Everything is fine, this code will work if I have twitter account on my device.
BUT! I need twitter login and password to be typed in my info screen in my application.
So I need to perform this action but with my custom login data, not by login data pulled from twitter account. For ex. I need the same to tweet but with login: 123 and password: qwerty.

Help me please, How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ios5 then twitter framework like email does not provide this facility. So if you want your custom login dialog then use S_OAuth.You can follow this link: http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-your-iphone-t1836.html